# Improving merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm

I am practicing merge sort and am curious if my second version is better than the first -- it seems to be in terms of memory requirement since I am popping from a list instead of just moving indices

Version 1:

```
def mergesort(L):
    if len(L)<=1: return L
    pivot=len(L)/2
    left=mergesort(L[:pivot])
    right=mergesort(L[pivot:])
    i=j=0
    sortedArr=[]
    while i<len(left) and j<len(right):
        if left[i]<right[j]:
            sortedArr.append(left[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            sortedArr.append(right[j])
            j+=1
    return sortedArr + left[i:] + right[j:]
```

Version 2

```
def mergesort(L):
    if len(L)<=1: return L
    pivot=len(L)/2
    left=mergesort(L[:pivot])
    right=mergesort(L[pivot:])
    sortedArr=[]
    while left!=[] and right!=[]:
        if left[0]<right[0]:
            sortedArr.append(left.pop(0))
        else:
            sortedArr.append(right.pop(0))
    return sortedArr + left + right
```

Without getting into parallelizing, is there any way to further improve upon Version 2, assuming it is superior to Version 1? How would I describe the memory requirements of these two versions so far?

Comment: Popping from the front of a list is going to be horribly inefficient.

Comment: In terms of memory, you're probably better with version2, but with computation, each `pop` requires python to shift the elements in memory of the list to the left by 1 which will be quite inefficient.  I suppose you could reverse the lists and pop off the end to fix that ...

Comment: @mgilson Is reversing a list expensive?

Comment: It should be O(N) in pretty optimized python code.  (and you do it by `lst[::-1]`).

Comment: So I am assuming that the cost of reversal is O(N) but popping a list is also O(N) since it has to shift everything down one spot, hence costly if we need to pop every element from L at some point (effectively O(N^2)?)

Comment: Right.  Popping every element from the left of `L` is an O(N*N) operation.

Comment: And so if we go with Version 1, is the extra memory requirement O(2N) because we have the sorted left and right lists (size N/2 and N/2) and then the merged result (size N)? Version 2 would have O(N) memory requirement but at the expense of speed? Would it have O(1) auxillary if I instead split the initial list into two lists left and right (instead of making extras) and then sorted each with the pop method?

Comment: Note that you are using O(NlogN) extra memory during the recursive calls. If you want to have a memory efficient version you should never slice the original list, and instead pass around the starting and ending indexes of the slice.

Answer (score 1):

why not using a deque from collections ? It would lower the cost of the popleft() operation ?

Answer (score 0):

For a list `L`, `L[:n]` operation is `O(n)` time, `O(n)` space in Python (it creates a new list with `n` elements).

Given `a`, `b`, `c` lists, `a + b + c` is `O(n)` time and space, where `n` is `len(a) + len(b) + len(c)` (it also creates a new list with `n` elements).

Thus each call to `mergesort()` requires [`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+2T%28n%2F2%29+%2B+n) time and space i.e., `T(n) = O(n*log(n))`.

Your second version has worse time complexity due to `left.pop(0)` that is `O(len(left))` operation. The memory requirements for the second version are asymptotically the same as for the first one.

Here's `O(n*log(n))` time, `O(n)` space solution with the same structure (using Python 3.3+ syntax):

```py
def mergesort(L):
    return list(merge_sort_gen(L, 0, len(L)))

def merge_sort_gen(L, start, n): # O(n*log(n)) time, O(n) space
    if n == 1:  # a list of one element is always sorted
        yield L[start]
    elif n > 1: # sort halves and merge them
        half = n // 2
        yield from merge(merge_sort_gen(L, start, half),
                         merge_sort_gen(L, start + half, n - half))
```

Where `merge()` merges two sorted iterators. You could use [`heapq.merge()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) or:

```py
from functools import partial

def merge(sorted_a, sorted_b, done=object()): # O(n) time, O(1) space
    next_a, next_b = partial(next, sorted_a, done), partial(next, sorted_b, done)

    a, b = next_a(), next_b()
    while a is not done and b is not done:
        if b < a:
            yield b
            b = next_b()
        else:
            yield a
            a = next_a()

    item, rest = (a, sorted_a) if b is done else (b, sorted_b)
    yield item #XXX at least one of sorted_a or sorted_b must be non-empty
    yield from rest
```

You could [follow the code step by step at Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=from+functools+import+partial%0A%0Adef+merge_sort_gen(L,+start,+n)%3A+%23+O(n*log(n))+time,+O(n)+space%0A++++if+n+%3D%3D+1%3A++%23+a+list+of+one+element+is+always+sorted%0A++++++++yield+L%5Bstart%5D%0A++++elif+n+%3E+1%3A+%23+sort+halves+and+merge+them%0A++++++++half+%3D+n+//+2%0A++++++++yield+from+merge(merge_sort_gen(L,+start,+half),%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++merge_sort_gen(L,+start+%2B+half,+n+-+half))%0A%0A%0Adef+merge(sorted_a,+sorted_b,+done%3Dobject())%3A+%23+O(n)+time,+O(1)+space%0A++++next_a,+next_b+%3D+partial(next,+sorted_a,+done),+partial(next,+sorted_b,+done)%0A%0A++++a,+b+%3D+next_a(),+next_b()%0A++++while+a+is+not+done+and+b+is+not+done%3A%0A++++++++if+b+%3C+a%3A%0A++++++++++++yield+b%0A++++++++++++b+%3D+next_b()%0A++++++++else%3A%0A++++++++++++yield+a%0A++++++++++++a+%3D+next_a()%0A+++%0A++++item,+rest+%3D+(a,+sorted_a)+if+b+is+done+else+(b,+sorted_b)%0A++++yield+item%0A++++yield+from+rest%0A%0A++++%0Ax+%3D+%5B3,+1,+2%5D%0Aprint(list(merge_sort_gen(x,+0,+len(x))))&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=3&curInstr=0).

`yield from iterable` produces the same items as (but the internal details are different):

```py
for item in iterable:
    yield item
```

See [The Python `yield` keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/4279).